# Why entityframework does not work in class libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity

I am using ef code-first ,
I want to have my entities in a class library project, but there is problem, I added entityFramework from NuGet but I can't use it and when I want to reference project :
have error in image
http://f.roozbehi.ir/Screenshot%20(40).png

Here is my **project.json** code :

```
     "version": "1.0.0-*",
     "description": "Entities Class Library",
     "authors": [ "haviro" ],
     "tags": [ "" ],
     "projectUrl": "",
     "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
     },

    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet": { }
     }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Probably a good idea to use the new .Net Core .csproj format instead of project.json which is already deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot and the project json represents that you haven't added any Target (dotnet) frameworks. So you are unable to access EntityFramework. Try adding a target framework through properties or through JSON.